# jquery navigation not working in webkit browsers

Tags: jquery, webkit, cross-browser

I've noticed the navigation on my site doesn't work in Safari or Chrome(it works fine in Firefox). 
In both browsers, it appears but clicking is disabled. What could be the cause and how can I repair?

ETA for clarity:
*In Chrome, the menu will load and you CAN click, but the page doesn't scroll to the section as it should nor does the menu follow along if you manually scroll. Also, the discs do not appear to the left side. In Safari, the menu appears as do the discs however clicking is disabled completely as is the follow along scroll.

**Also, I'm certain this is not exclusive to my machine as it was another person that brought these problems to my attention(ie- this problem has been shown on two different machines by two different users***

[live site](http://frshstudio.com)

html

```
<nav>
    <ul id="Nav">
        <li><a href="#home">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">manifesta</a></li>
        <li><a href="#services">services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#lookbook">lookbook</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#optin">goodies</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://frshstudio.com/blog">blog</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

css

```
nav {
    position: fixed;
    right: 9%;
    top: 55%
}

nav ul { 

        list-style-type:disc;
    }

    nav ul li {
        text-align: right;
        color: #fff;
    }

    nav ul li.current {
        color:#000;
    }
```

Comment: Menu works as it should with Firefox but also with Chrome on my Linux box!

Comment: @PetjaTouru In Chrome, the menu will load and you CAN click, but the page doesn't scroll to the section as it should nor does the menu follow along if you manually scroll. Also, the discs do not appear to the left side. In Safari, the menu appears as do the discs however clicking is disabled completely as is the follow along scroll.

Comment: works fine in Chrome v27 for me.

Comment: There appears to be some serious animation lag. In my Safari, I don't get link actions on the nav's apparent position. I *do* get link actions where the nav *should* be - and anytime I scroll, it takes between 5-10 seconds for the nav to catch up and display where the link actions are occurring. After the first page, sometimes the nav doesn't redisplay at all - link actions are *always* there though.

Comment: @CodeMoose Thanks for the explanation. Do you have any idea what I can do to make it function a bit better/quicker?

Comment: Working on that for you now - hopefully I'll have an answer shorty!

Comment: Your issue obviously involves javascript code. Please post the relevant code, and state the librairies you use.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't find the exact reason this is happening, but webkit browsers (ie Chrome and Safari) are notorious for their animation artifacts on rich pages. I see files included for slideshow, smooth scrolling, pinterest and google APIs, and a few for theme support - I think the browser is too busy managing these to make its css behaviors seamless.

Since you're already using jquery, instead of making the nav `position: fixed;` I'd suggest positioning it absolutely and using jquery to animate its position - keep `right: 9%;` and make `top:` an explicit pixel distance based on the scroll position. There's a million plugins for this already, so I'm sure you can find one that works for you without much effort. Start here: http://www.jquery4u.com/menus/floating-message-plugins/.

Comment: By the way, awesome-looking site - hope you can iron out the rest of the wrinkles in it!

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice and kind words. I'll investigate the plugins you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the cross-browser working DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/KBF7N/

You don't need to use any other plug-in for scrolling navigation. Just these small scripts can give you the effect you want.

Add `target` attribute to `<a>` tag with the same DIV id name that you want to animate instead of `href`.

## HTML

```
<nav>
    <ul id="Nav">
        <li><a target="home">home</a></li>
        <li><a target="about">manifesta</a></li>
        <li><a target="services">services</a></li>
        <li><a target="lookbook">lookbook</a></li>
        <li><a target="contact">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<div id="home">home</div>
<div id="about">manifesta</div>
<div id="services">services</div>
<div id="lookbook">lookbook</div>
<div id="contact">contact</div>
```

## JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#Nav li a').on('click',function(){
        $("#Nav li").removeClass('current');
        $(this).parent('li').addClass('current');
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#'+$(this).attr('target')).offset().top }, 'slow'); 
    });
});
```

## CSS

```
body {
    background:#ccc;
    margin: 0;
    height: 2000px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
}
nav {
    position: fixed;
    right: 9%;
    top: 55%
}
nav ul { 
        list-style-type:disc;
    }
    nav ul li {
        text-align: right;
        color: #fff;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
    nav ul li a{
        color: #000;
    }
    nav ul li.current {
        color:#000;
    }
#home, #about, #services, #lookbook, #contact{
    float:left;
    width:94%;
    height:600px;
    margin:20px 3%;
    background:#ccc;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:100px;
    border:3px solid #555;      
}
```

Comment: Applying the code above generated 2 nav menus, and disabled nav capabilities all together. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found the source of your problem. It's your content slider (RevSlider) within #home. If you remove the class "tp-simpleresponsive" from the div "rev_slider revslider-initialised tp-simpleresponsive", then everything starts working 100%. This tells me you have a JS conflict or error.

It might be worth checking to see if you even need that class in there.